# How can I get NHibernate to delete orphans in a one-to-one relationship?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

We have an object in our model, call it class X. There are several other classes in our model that have an instance of class X as a property, call them A, B, C, etc. This is essentially a one-to-one mapping, since each X can only belong to one parent class. To map this relationship on the database side, we are currently using a foreign key to the X table in tables A, B, and C. For the NHibernate mappings, we are currently using, in the mappings for the A, B, and C classes:

```
ManyToOne(a => a.X, m => m.Cascade(Cascade.All));
```

This mostly works for saving, retrieving, and updating our class Xs - we've had a lot of problems getting NHibernate `OneToOne` mappings to work right. The problem is that, when you take your persistent class A and replace its X with a new instance of X and then save that A instance, then the new X instance gets written to the database and the foreign key in the A column gets updated, but the old X does not get deleted, so we now have an orphan X.

We would like those orphaned Xes to be automatically deleted. We would like NHibernate to do it, because X is a complex class with many relationships of its own to other tables that we have cascades set up to handle properly - I have a SQL script set up to delete orphan Xes properly, and it's about 50 lines long.

We are trying to avoid solutions that involve putting a reference in class X to its parent item, since there are a total of 5 classes that it can belong to, and situations such as class A has one X, class B has 2 Xes in named properties, etc.

Things I've tried so far:

Adding `DeleteOrphans` to the `ManyToOne` mapping - doesn't work

`OneToOne` mapping - really wants the key to be in the other table, and doesn't seem to support cascade deletes anyways.

Also considered:

NHibernate doesn't seem to have any support for setting up some kind of even to trigger when things like updates or deletes happen

Apparantly, only the `OneToMany` and `ManyToMany` mappings support `DeleteOrphans`, so, I could make the actual property use some kind of list or set, and use getters and setters to make it look like a normal property to the rest of the model. Sounds very hacky, and it might require having a reference in X to the other classes.

Database trigger - I haven't really checked if SQL Server triggers can be used in this way yet, but it sounds like a very awkward solution.

Does anybody have any ideas for how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that we ended up going with here is to never allow a new instance of X to be assigned to any of the classes that hold it. Instead, we have added code to the setters so that, whenever you try to assign a new instance of X, it will actually clear the contents of the existing X and replace them all with the contents of the new X. Since all of the objects contained in X are collections, NHibernate cascade deletes work properly in deleting the old child items of X and replacing them with the new ones. It's a bit of an ugly solution, but it's the least ugly thing we've been able to come up with that works.